# href changes but the page is redirected after the page is fully loaded using jquery in chrome

Tags: jquery, google-chrome

I am facing a weird bug in CHROME. The code works fine for firefox.

```
$.ajax({
    url: someurl,
    type: 'POST',
    data: {},
    headers: headers,
    success: function(data) {
        if (data.href) {
            // create cookies
            if (manager) {
                window.location.href = "/index.html";
            } else if (admin) {
                window.location.href = "/admin.html";
            } else {
                window.location.href = "/tester.html";
            }
        }
    },
    error: function(data) {
        $('#error').html("Invalid username or password.");
    }
});
```

If the page's url is changed to someurl/index.html and there are large number of ajax calls than the href changes instantly but the page is redirected to someurl/index.html after all data is loaded.

Comment: Of course it will redirect as you are using `window.location.href`. What do you want to achieve actually?

Comment: This will redirecting but is redirecting from current page after the page has been fully loaded. I want it to redirect before the page is loaded. This is exactly that is happening in chrome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I identified the problem and worked out the solution.

The problem was with async ajax call. I made the async false before the call and set it to true after the call. This worked in every case.

```
async = false;

$.ajax({
    url: someurl,
    type: 'POST',
    data: {},
    async : false,
    headers: headers,
    success: function(data) {
        if (data.href) {
            // create cookies
            if (manager) {
                window.location.href = "/index.html";
            } else if (admin) {
                window.location.href = "/admin.html";
            } else {
                window.location.href = "/tester.html";
            }
        }
    },
    error: function(data) {
        $('#error').html("Invalid username or password.");
    }
});
async = true;
```

Answer (score 0):

run your ajax call like this

```
$(window).load(function() {
  // ajax call 
});
```

Comment: why do you think this would make a difference?

Comment: Don't know why but this made the system unresponsive. setTimeout(funciton() {},100); worked for me. Thanks anyways.